# OnClickListener is not showing output of my function

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I make the 2 function , one function is give brightness to the image and second function is converting image into grayscale , below is my jni code for it (I am using android with eclipse)

```
int toGray(Mat mSrc, Mat& bgra);
int tobrightness(Mat mSrc, Mat& bgra);

extern "C" {

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_opencv_samples_NativeActivity_CvNativeActivity_grayimg(JNIEnv* env, jobject,jint width, jint height, jintArray in, jintArray out)
   {
       jint* _in = env->GetIntArrayElements(in, 0);
       jint* _out = env->GetIntArrayElements(out, 0);

       Mat mSrc(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*)_in);
       Mat bgra(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*)_out);

       int conv;
       jint retVal;
       conv = toGray(mSrc ,bgra);
       retVal = (jint)conv;

       env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(in, _in, 0);
       env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(out, _out, 0);
       return retVal;

   }
}


JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_opencv_samples_NativeActivity_CvNativeActivity_eqhist(JNIEnv* env, jobject,jint width, jint height, jintArray in, jintArray out)
   {
       jint* _in = env->GetIntArrayElements(in, 0);
       jint* _out = env->GetIntArrayElements(out, 0);

       Mat mSrc(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*)_in);
       Mat bgra(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*)_out);
       Mat bgr(height, width, CV_8UC3);
       int conv;
       jint retVal;
       conv = tobrightness(mSrc, bgra);
       retVal = (jint)conv;

       env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(in, _in, 0);
       env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(out, _out, 0);
       return retVal;

}
int tobrightness(Mat mSrc, Mat& bgra)
{
    vector<Mat> sChannels;
    split(mSrc, sChannels);

    for(int i=0; i<sChannels.size(); i++)
    {
        Mat channel = sChannels[i];
        equalizeHist(channel, channel);
    }
    merge(sChannels, bgra);
    return 1;
}

int toGray(Mat mSrc, Mat& bgra)
{
    Mat gray(mSrc.rows, mSrc.cols, CV_8UC1);
    cvtColor(mSrc , gray , CV_BGRA2GRAY);
    cvtColor(gray , bgra , CV_GRAY2BGRA);
    return 1;
}
```

Is it `Okay` to call it twice/thrice or many times jni method in one cpp file like above I did ? As I want that if **I click on one button it should perform the function of brightness and when I click on the second button it should perform grayscale** , so am I going right with above cpp for this scenerio ?

below is my java code :

```
public class CvNativeActivity extends Activity
{
    public native int eqhist(int width, int height, int [] mPhotoIntArray, int [] mCannyOutArray);
    public native int grayimg(int width, int height, int [] mPhotoIntArray, int [] mCannyOutArray);

    static 
    {
        System.loadLibrary("native_activity");
        Log.i("EqActivity", "native library loaded successfully");
    }
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
    ImageView imageview_1;
    ImageView imageview_2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
         imageview_1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
         imageview_2=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        InputStream is;
        is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.me);
        Bitmap bmInImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

        int [] mPhotoIntArray;
        int [] mCannyOutArray;

        mPhotoIntArray = new int[bmInImg.getWidth() * bmInImg.getHeight()];
        imageview_1.setImageBitmap(bmInImg);
        // Copy pixel data from the Bitmap into the 'intArray' array
        bmInImg.getPixels(mPhotoIntArray, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight());

        //create the Brightness result buffer
        mCannyOutArray = new int[bmInImg.getWidth() * bmInImg.getHeight()];


        eqhist(bmInImg.getHeight(), bmInImg.getWidth(), mPhotoIntArray, mCannyOutArray);
        grayimg(bmInImg.getHeight(), bmInImg.getWidth(), mPhotoIntArray, mCannyOutArray);

        //
        // Convert the result to Bitmap
        //
        Bitmap bmOutImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);  
        bmOutImg.setPixels(mCannyOutArray, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight());


        imageview_2.setImageBitmap(bmOutImg);
        String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        String outFileName = extStorageDirectory + "/me.png";

        OutputBitmapToFile(bmOutImg, outFileName);   
    }
}
void OutputBitmapToFile(Bitmap InBm, String Filename)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        InBm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);

        File f = new File(Filename);
        try
        {
            f.createNewFile();
            //write the bytes in file
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
}
```

*Above code work fine and showing output for eqhist method*

But Calling function through button click (I adjusted below code in above code and getting no error but its not showing output) :

```
Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.NextButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                eqhist(bmInImg.getHeight(), bmInImg.getWidth(), mPhotoIntArray, mCannyOutArray);

            }
        });
```

Error :

```
08-05 00:42:21.656: E/ActivityManager(360): writeStringToFile error: /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_enabled java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_enabled: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
08-05 00:57:56.150: E/ActivityManager(360): ANR in org.opencv.samples.NativeActivity (org.opencv.samples.NativeActivity/.CvNativeActivity)
08-05 00:57:56.150: E/ActivityManager(360): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
08-05 01:18:16.986: E/Trace(20443): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

**Edit :**

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
     >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
         />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/NextButton"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
     android:text="@string/Next_Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can have multiple functions as long as they have unique jni-compatible names.

Comment: @ChrisStratton But when I call the `jni` function through button , its not working after button click , its force to close the application

Comment: Show the stack trace from logcat

Comment: That's not the real error, it will be earlier.

Comment: I update it with error in logcat

Comment: You are doing too much work on the UI thread on blocking on it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I just design 2 image view and one button , can you elaborate the error ? I just trying again and again and I think its something wrong with imageview2

Comment: I award bounty for it

Comment: As I said before, you are doing too much work on the UI thread.  You haven't really provided enough information to figure out what you might be doing there which is taking too long, so unless you get very lucky it is unlikely anyone will provide a meaningful answer, though bounties do tend to bring out absurd guesses.

Comment: I updated my question , with all information I am giving and getting from eclipse

Comment: So are you doing anything with the `mCannyOutArray` output data in `onClick()`? I don't see any evidence of that.

Comment: @laalto mCannyOutArray returns output from jni , it work with bmOutImg in java end to save .png

Comment: There is no problem with your `.cpp` file , not with activity and manifest.xml , something is wrong in java , what about your logcat ?

Comment: logcat showing no error and once which i got i put it in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i said in comment your doing very little error in java file , your other files are okay , you are not putting your result on button click so button have nothing to display (no imageview) , your output bitmap is outside the button click , your bitmap has nothing to display on button click , Put these lines inside the button click

```
Bitmap bmOutImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);  
bmOutImg.setPixels(mCannyOutArray, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight());   
imageview_2.setImageBitmap(bmOutImg);
```

below code works for me as I tested on android but its bit slow :

```
Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.NextButton);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
public void onClick(View v)  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("APP: ", "Into OnClick of SettingDialog. View = " + v);
        eqhist(bmInImg.getHeight(),bmInImg.getWidth(), mPhotoIntArray, mCannyOutArray); 
        Bitmap bmOutImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);  
        bmOutImg.setPixels(mCannyOutArray, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight());   
        imageview_2.setImageBitmap(bmOutImg);


    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do it twice. You can have it one call.

```
extern "C" {

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_opencv_samples_NativeActivity_CvNativeActivity_grayimg(JNIEnv* env, jobject,jint width, jint height, jintArray in, jintArray out)
   {
       // process
   }

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_opencv_samples_NativeActivity_CvNativeActivity_eqhist(JNIEnv* env, jobject,jint width, jint height, jintArray in, jintArray out)
   {
       // process
   }
}
int tobrightness(Mat mSrc, Mat& bgra)
{
    // process
}

int toGray(Mat mSrc, Mat& bgra)
{
    // process
}
```

Now in your `CvNativeActivity` you need to define following functions.

```
public native int grayimg(int w, int h, int[] in, int[] out);
public native int eqhist(int w, int h, int[] in, int[] out);
```

And it seems that you are getting error while writing Bitmap to .png file. Update your question with `OutputBitmapToFile` function.

One more possible solution would be to call this function in a new thread.

```
public class ProcessTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground() {
        // this happens in a background thread
        eqhist(bmInImg.getHeight(), bmInImg.getWidth(), mPhotoIntArray, mCannyOutArray);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // save image, show image etc
        // This happens on the UI thread
    }
}
```

And your onClick call,

```
Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.NextButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 ProcessTask task = new ProcessTask();
                 task.execute();

            }
        })
```

Comment: I update my question and i want work these functions on button click

Comment: couple of things. Could you make sure that that file is being saved(OutoutBitmapToFile funection being called) using Log. Also, you haven't added user-permission to write to external storage in your manifest.

Comment: But everything works fine when I didn't use this button click

Comment: try this. Add a function via onClick to your button. Remove onClickListener as of now. See if it works or not.

Comment: Same result , when i put log on button , it give me following log output : `08-07 21:47:16.900: I/APP:(5548): Into OnClick of SettingDialog. View = android.widget.Button@420d2f10`

Comment: Your xml has `Next_Button` and you are finding it by `NextButton`. Make sure that this is correct.

Comment: Its showing error on Next_Button , i change it in string.xml `<string name="Next_Button">Next</string>`