# Eclipse - ButtonCLick --> new screen with text

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, click

Im kinda new on developing for Android, and now i have decided to make a simple apps for my frens and me.

I know how to design the layout, but when it comes to the "activity" I always messes things up..

So now to my question - I'm creating a app to show my college schedule so I have 6 buttons (monday tuesday wednesday etc.) Then when I click each button I want to get to another screen with todays schedule..

How to I create new screens in an easy way? please answer steps by steps with screenshot...

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

1. What you are calling a new screen is `Activity`. Read [what is Activity and its Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).
2. Read How to create activities: [Best way to add Activity to an Android project in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337874/best-way-to-add-activity-to-an-android-project-in-eclipse)

   Since you've mentioned that you've already created the `Button`s do this:
3. See How to set a listener on Buttons, so that you can perform some action on it (eg: start Activity) when Button is clicked. Read [Android: how to handle button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782901/android-how-to-handle-button-click)
4. See How to start a new Activity: [How to start new activity on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click)

Its turns out that rather than steps by step pictures, what is required is breaking the problem into multiple small problems and try to search if anyone has solved it before.

This would be the starting point. Hope it helps.

Comment: If you dont mind, please show me some sample of code or tutorials or screenshot..This will indeed help for me...

Comment: Well, the links I gave have sample code for what you need.