# Opening a new activity using both spinners and a button

Tags: android

I basically have a spinner displaying an three items. I want it so that if Click on one of these three items and then click a button it will open up a new activity.

```
 String[] count;
Spinner s;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button view = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    s = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    count = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country_array);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,count);
    s.setAdapter(adapter);
    view.setEnabled(false); // initially disable the button
    s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                   long id) {
            view.setEnabled(true); // enable when user selects any item
        }
        // Listen to button click
        view.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //start activity
                startActivity();
            }
        }
    });
    public void startActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Based on what item user has selected do you want to open different activities?

Comment: yeh so if I had three countries us , canada and mexico. I select mexico from the list and then you click the button. Once button is clicked it opens new activity.

Comment: And you don't want to allow the user to press the button before he selects one of the 3, right?

Comment: yeh that would be nice too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
view.setEnabled(false); // initially disable the button
s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
         view.setEnabled(true); // enable when user selects any item
    }
```

See how to listen to Button click: [Android: how to handle button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782901/android-how-to-handle-button-click)

```
// Listen to button click
view.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //start activity
                startActivity();
            }
        });


public void startActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: hmm i understand how to use the button but im not sure where to place the code you gave me

Comment: Except the `startActivity` function place it in `onCreate()` after `.setAdapter`.

Comment: ok so I did that already and I was getting a bunch of errors.

Comment: put `statActivity()` function definition outside the `onCreate()` function. You are defining one function inside other. I think going over basic would be better first than. Hope it helps.