# How to set a button outside listview

Tags: android

In my activity I have a listview and a button. Each has separate purpose.

My listview shows an item details in another activity.

My button opens another activity.

Here listview does not have any problem. But my button does not work.

In my code I have used following sample for listview and button

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListView.OnItemClickListener{

   private Button buttonaddticket;

    private ListView listView;
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.MainActivity );

            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.srListView);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

            buttonaddticket = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnaddticket);

            //Setting listeners to button
            buttonaddticket.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

        }
        .
        .
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SingleTicket.class);
        .
        }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == buttonaddticket){
        .
        .
        }
    }
        }
```

Question is how can I implement onClickListener in same activity for my button?

Comment: yourButton.setOnClickListener()

Comment: set listner on your button in oncreate simply

Comment: Yes I have tried this already but it seems OnClickListener and OnItemClickListener does not work in same activity

Comment: please share your code what you have done for button

Comment: @tanvir You mean if button works then list doesn't and if list works button doesn't . is it ? I suggest adding more and real codes you've done removing sensitive parts if necessary.

Comment: Here I updated my code. As I said listview works fine but button doesn't.

Comment: You are wrong in `if(v == buttonaddticket)`, change it to `if(v.getId() == R.id.buttonaddticket)`

Comment: @Phan Văn Linh,Tried already, it gives error.

Comment: @tanvir http://stackoverflow.com/a/14783194/5381331, please see it

Comment: @Phan Văn Linh, I have read. But still problems seems to OnItemClickListener and setOnClickListener, are you sure they work in same activity?

Comment: @tanvir please post your update code. and also you forgot implement `View.OnClickListener` in the activity. please see my answer again

Comment: delete the cast to (View.OnClickListener) and implement View.OnClickListener in the activity. It should work then.

Comment: Thanks guys. The problem was to implement View.OnClickListener in class. I have already answered my question.

Comment: @tanvir but why you don't accept my answer as correct answer. I think my answer solve your problem, right?

Comment: @Phan Văn Linh, yes sure. I could not see `,View.OnClickListener` if I don't scroll. Now I can see that :). Thank you so much for your effort.

Comment: @tanvir no problem bro, happy coding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implements multiple `Listener` for your `Activity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListView.OnItemClickListener,View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         // handle listview on item click
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
         switch (view.getId()){
                    //handle multiple view click events
         }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is get the reference to the button and use the "View.OnClickListener" interface in order to get the click to register. In order to make sure the button registers the click it needs to have its listener set to "this" activity. This will allow your list to pick up the clicks individually compared to your button.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListView.OnItemClickListener, View.OnClickListener {

  private Button yourButton;
  private ListView listView;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.MainActivity);

      yourButton = (Button) findViewById(/* Your button id */);
      yourButton.setOnClickListener(this);

      listView = (ListView) findViewById(/* Your list id */);
      listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     // handle listview item click here
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view){
       //Handle button click here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!!!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListView.OnItemClickListener, View.OnClickListener {

 private Button buttonaddticket;
 private ListView listView;

 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.MainActivity);

   buttonaddticket = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnaddticket);
   buttonaddticket.setOnClickListener(this);

   listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.srListView);

  listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
 }

@Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
 // handle listview item click here
}

 @Override
 public void onClick(View view){
   switch(view.getId()){
   case R.id.btnaddticket:

   // Enter Code here     
   break;

   }
 }
}
```