# android studio button class not getting invoked

Tags: android, android-studio

[enter image description here][1]This is my first android studio project. Unable to invoke the Button class despite import the widget.Button package.  Pl guide.[Main activity screen shot.[][[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaP0W.png)

Comment: You will find your answer here : [How to handle button click][1]
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14783194/5424676

Comment: You will find your answer here : [How to handle button click][1]
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14783194/5424676

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking how to handle a button click? 

`Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
clickButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
                **Do what you want with the click here**
            }
        });`

Answer (score 0):

I guess by button class you mean the action once the button has been clicked.
First step:
**Add OnClick on XML**
Second step:
**Call the name of activity in Java class**
Third step:
Write the action to be taken OnClick.

Comment: Thanks much. My issue is even before that stage. in the MainActivity.kt, i have imported the android.widget.Button package.  When the following code is written for creation of Button object: Button obj = ....... I get an error message prompting ---- Function Invocation 'Button(....)' expected. It states none of the functions can be called with the arguments supplied. pl guide.

Comment: Do not add pictures of code. Instead copy your code and paste it as text.

Comment: package com.example.sudhakarvijayasarathy.firsttest.feature

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button)
    }
}