# How to add view to constraint layout at runtime?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, androidx

I want to update my Constraint layout by adding textfields on button click. so far I'm using constraint set but my layout is not update.

Methond to create additional textfield

```
private void createUtilForm(){
    titleInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(this);
    int titleId = ViewCompat.generateViewId();
    Log.d("AddEmployee", "createUtilForm: titleId"+ titleId);
    titleInputLayout.setId(titleId);
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams clpTitle = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_CONSTRAINT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    childConstraintLayout.addView(titleInputLayout, clpTitle);

    ConstraintSet utilFordSet = new ConstraintSet();

    utilFordSet.clone(childConstraintLayout);
    utilFordSet.connect(titleInputLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START);
    utilFordSet.connect(titleInputLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END);
    utilFordSet.connect(titleInputLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, allowanceHeaderTV.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
    utilFordSet.connect(deductionHeaderTV.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, titleInputLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);

    utilFordSet.applyTo(childConstraintLayout);
}
```

XML Layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AddEmployeeActivity">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/child_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/add_employee_toolbar">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/child_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/allowance_header_tv"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="@string/allowance_header_hint"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/allowance_add_ib"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/allowance_add_ib"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/allowance_header_tv"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/allowance_header_tv"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/deduction_header_tv"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="@string/deduction_header_hint"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/deduction_add_ib"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/allowance_header_tv" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/deduction_add_ib"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/img_desc_label"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/deduction_header_tv"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/deduction_header_tv"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Is it obvious that you tried to make a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) doing your best. The only problem I see here is that your English is a little hard to understand. I will try to guess what you try to say the best I can as well. Perhaps you are trying to bind your method to a button, so when you click it the method executes?

Comment: It looks like your `<Button>` is not present in the XML sample you provided... so, my answer will be based on a hypothetical `<button>` widget, if you don't mind...

Comment: However, your question seems to be a duplicate of [Android: how to handle button click](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14782901/3692177).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: how to handle button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782901/android-how-to-handle-button-click)

Comment: Hi, @SebasSBM, I just realized, I should have structured the question properly. I wanted to create Views programmatically(using constraint layout) so that I can set their ids.

Comment: @Ismali You can edit your question to re-structure it if you think it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did in past..!

1: Just create an **empty linear layout** inside the constraint layout of your **Acitivity.XML** file and **define constraints** if any.

2: Create a **textfield.XML** file for your text fields

3: Add this code in your **Activity java.**

```
 public void addLayout() {


    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    final View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.textfield, null);

    linearLayout.addView(row, linearLayout.getChildCount() - 1);

}
```

but If you have a **fragment java** change into this

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

And **how to Remove**.

```
  public void RemoveLayout() {
        if (linearLayout.getChildCount() > 0) {
            linearLayout.removeViewAt(linearLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your button is like this in your XML layout:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/addTextViewButton"
    [...] />
```

You can get a reference to the button like this:

```
Button myButton = findViewById(R.id.addTextViewButton);
```

If you make the button from java code, you will need it stored in some variable to attach the method.

You can attach a method to your button like this. Add this within your Activity's `onCreate` method:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        createUtilForm();
    }
});
```

But this code could be structured in other ways. In [this link](https://hackernoon.com/4-ways-to-implement-onclicklistener-on-android-9b956cbd2928) other ways to implement `OnClickListener`s are explained.