# TextView wont redirect me to my registration activity from login

Tags: java, android

When I click on the Sign up txt on my application it crashes I've tried almost everything i could find including the XML `onClick`

XML clickable 
onClick

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    TextView sign_up_text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        sign_up_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sign_up);
        sign_up_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));

            }
        });

    }

}
```

**xml:**

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sign_up_text"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/sign_up"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        />
```

Android app crashes with no failure

Comment: have you declared activity in manifest?

Comment: Remove `android:onClick="onClick" ` from your layout. Use any one listener.

Comment: My manifest is the problem. I commented it out because I was receiving errors trying to add all the activities

Comment: what problem are you facing adding Activity to **AndroidManifest.xml.** you have to add activity to manifest file.

If you remove `android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity"` if not needed.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: **Note:** You should not update previous question with new question-texts. you can update it by adding new issue or you can add new question as well.

Answer (score 4):

You have **`android:onClick="onClick"`** attribute in your xml. And you have also define **`sign_up_text.setOnClickListener`** in java.

You can do only one thing at a time.

**1.**

If you want to use **`sign_up_text.setOnClickListener`** , you simply need to remove **`android:onClick="onClick"`** from xml file.(*[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15868484/2289835)*)

**2.**

If you want to use **`android:onClick="onClick"`**, you should define new method in your activity like:(*[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38749267/2289835)*)

```
public void onClick(View view) {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

First solution is to remove `android:onClick="onClick"` from your XML, according to my perception the reason of crash is the function name called on `onClick` of your button click define in XML is `"onClick"` which is also override function of `setOnClickListner`

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v){
         //todo your code
        }
```

Second Solution is if you use `onClick` in XMl change function name other that override function `onClick` like:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sign_up_text"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/sign_up"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="myFunction"
        />

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

}

private myFunction(View view){
}
```