# How to increase max length character limit of edit text in Android button by 10 in every click?

Tags: android, maxlength, input-filtering

Android maxLength: 500

```
EditText ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);

int maxLength= //current maxlength + 10 // im looking for the current max length code to add it with 10

ed.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new 

InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});
```

The output will be a total of 510 maxLength character input in first click of button and on second click it will be 520 and so on and so fort.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: how to handle button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782901/android-how-to-handle-button-click)

Comment: @jaidran what have you tried for it..Here we are all here to help you, but the only condition is that you need to put your effort on it

Comment: EditText ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
int maxLength= //looking for current maxlength + 10 
ed.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straight forward

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final int width = button.getLayoutParams().width + 10;
        final int height = button.getLayoutParams().height;
        button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));
    }
 });
```

Since your first question wasn't very clear here is the **update:**

```
int maxLength = 500;

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        maxlength = maxLength + 10;
        editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
            new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)
        });
    }
 });
```

Comment: Android maxLength: 500

EditText ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);

int maxLength= //current maxlength + 10 // im looking for the current max length code to add it with 10

ed.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new 

InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});

The output will be a total of 510 maxLength character input in first click of button and on second click it will be 520 and so on and so fort.